# How to decide which EC2 instance to use for Jenkins running 20 concurrent builds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

Basically I want to know, which EC2 instance can handle how many concurrent Jenkins build?

Please let me know if I need to elaborate the question.

Comment: don't use one use an ASG and a LB

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty new to aws. Looking into your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect answer. Setting up an auto-scaling group with a load-balancer is the "by the book" way to do it (option #2 below) - those two tools can be found in the EC2 area and allow you to launch multiple EC2 instances as needed, and automatically 'kill them off' when they aren't needed anymore.

A few options:

1. Choose the EC2 with the most computer power and see how it handles your 20 jobs. If things are moving slowly or it's unable to handle them, launch a new instance with more compute power.

   - Pros: Simple and Cost-Effective (most likely)
   - Cons: Might be time consuming initially to figure out how much CPU you need
2. Setup a load-balancer and auto-scaling group do distribute your workloads across multiple instances and scale as needed.

   - Pros: Guaranteed to handle your workload(s)
   - Cons: More expensive (most likely)

For Jenkins I use the AWS EC2 Plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin

If you go with option 1, you could install that plugin, one you figure out the proper amount of CPU you need to handle your job(s), save an 'image' of the EC2 and configure it to launch as a 'spot instance' when you need to run your jobs, and kill itself automatically after being idle for x amount of minutes. This route would be cost-effective and you could probably add an arbitrarily high amount of CPU to your AMI (Machine Image) since you're saving a good amount of money using 'spot instances'.

Again, an auto-scaling group with a load-balancer to distribute work across multiple nodes, and scale as needed (automatically) is the correct way to do it but until you get the hang of AWS it might be easier to try option #1 with the EC2 plugin. If you do go with the auto-scaling group and load-balancer, monitor the setup for a few weeks and make sure you don't accidentally launch a ton of unnecessary instances (happened to me, ran up my bill quite a bit).

This blog has some really good info about AWS EC2:

https://www.edureka.co/blog/ec2-aws-tutorial-elastic-compute-cloud/